# Amazon Dynamodb how to query using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I know this might be very easy for some of you but I am really new to dynamoDb and I am having a hard time understanding it. Would really appreciate if someone could provide me some guidance on this
I have the following table structure -

[image]

where NameID is my hash key and ManagerEmail is the range key. I want to pull all the results from my table specifically NameID those Last_login date is is more than 1 day from the current date. I know how to get difference between two dates

```
d1 = datetime.strptime(d1, "%Y-%m-%d")
d2 = datetime.strptime(d2, "%Y-%m-%d")
return abs((d2 - d1).days)
```

But I am not able to understand how to plug is in my dynamoDB query and get the required data using python boto3. Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you have a global/local secondary index against the `Last_login` column?

Comment: After creation of the table I have NameID[hash key] and ManagerEmail[sort key] in my table after which I use client.put_item() to add Last_login and Acc_creation_date. I am not sure if that answers your question

Comment: This is how put item looks like-         client.put_item(
            Item={
                'NameID': {
                    'S': NameID,
                },
                'ManagerEmail': {
                    'S': ManagerEmail,
                },
                'Acc_Creation_date': {
                    'S': creation_date,
                },
                'Last_login': {
                    'S': creation_date,
                }
            },
            TableName='Sandbox-Users'
        )